Geely EC7 2013 automatic transmission D,N,R,P blinking
From past a month i am having an issue with my car transmission D,N,R,P all blinking then i have to turn off the engine and start again. Sometimes turning off doesn't solve the problem then i have to reattached the neutral battery wire and it works fine. Usually it happens during mornings when driving car about 500 to 800 meters at slow speed. I have changed three mechanics and 1 gear shifting sensor and 1 speed sensor. Nothing solved the issue. I am wasting my money on this. Please someone help.
After a month i bought OBD 2 scanner and diagnosed the car got U0100 AND P0700 AND U1040. I cleared the codes and one month went smoothly like nothing happened. Yesterday i got same issue at the speed of 110 kmh, then did same thing as previous like i was doing everyday.
I have notice that whenever this blinking headache accurs the engine temperature sensor drops 2, 3 to 0 and suddenly goes 3 to 4. (I have total 8 points of engine cooling temperature.)
Upon reaching the 4th point the blinking issue happens. Usually.
Please help before i throw this car to garbage.
I am living in Saudi Arabia.
